# How to disable Google 360 tour scroll zoom?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-street-view

I'm using a purely `iframe` based virtual tour embed code. This is how the embed code look like:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!4v1516179112275!6m8!1m7!1sW42AXPaUi0AAAAQvO3Cikw!2m2!1d53.29123628241636!2d-6.200836469261503!3f308.93!4f1.4099999999999966!5f0.4000000000000002" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I am in need of disabling mouse wheel scroll zoom. I know, while using `google.maps.StreetViewPanorama` API we can disable scroll zoom by setting parameter `scrollWheeel` to `false`.

But, I'm not able to find any documentation to do the same with `iframe` based embed code. Only hacks are there like placing an overlay over `iframe` and hiding it on click event and again making it appear on mouse leave event.

Is there any official way to disable mouse wheel sroll zoom for Google 360 StreetViewPanorama virtual tour when using embed `iframe`?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no way to do this on the embed API but there is a [Feature Request](https://buganizer.corp.google.com/issues/35827294) currently open requesting for this. If you subscribe to it then it will gain more interest towards having it implemented.

The alternative like you said is to use the Google street view service in the maps javascript API.